# Angularjs: Required validation of dropdown inside ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Using angualrjs 1.3

I have a dropdown inside my ng-repeat as:

```
  <tr ng-repeat="c in myData">
    <td>
        <select name="type" class="form-control" ng-model="c.type" required>
             <option value="">--Select--</option>
             <option ng-repeat="type in types">{{type.text}}</option>
         </select>  
    </td>
  </tr>
```

How can i do required field validation of above dropdown.

I have other textbox controls in my ng-repeat where I used as below:

```
<td ng-class="{ 'has-error': myForm['comment_' + {{$index}}].$invalid && (myForm['comment__' + {{$index}}].$touched || myForm.$submitted) }">
        <input type="text" name="comment_{{$index}}" required ng-model="c.comment" class="form-control" />
    </td>
```

And the validation works, but when I try to apply same to the dropdown it does not work.

Any inputs ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angularjs is large and intelligent library which you can do everything on it, in your sample you can use `ng-form` and `ng-options` and `ng-required` instead common html codes and track input by `$index` as this sample.

> with `ng-form` you can define each `tr` as a form and then you can check form validation.

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.controller("ctrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.myData = [
      {},{}
    ]
    
    $scope.types = [1,2,3]
});
```

```css
.has-error {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.20/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <table>
     <tr ng-repeat="c in myData" ng-form="x">
        <td>
          <select ng-model="c.type" ng-options="option for option in types" ng-required="true"></select>
        </td>
        <td>
           <input type="text" ng-model="c.text" ng-required="true" />
        </td>
        <td ng-class="{'has-error': x.$invalid}">
          form is valid: {{x.$valid}}
        </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: I needed to add default value as select so that user can select a value so I added this line:  <option value="">Select</option> as option.  I am not using ng-form here. Can I somehow highlight the td row without using this, someway like I am using in my TD above in my sample code